# Why method addObject() with association Many-to-Many not working in migrate Sequelize?

Tags: node.js, model, many-to-many, migrate, sequelize-cli

I have **User** model, **Team** model, **relationship User_Team** and migrate file is **create-user_team**.
Why, when I use the code following Sequelize's instructions  `const result = await team.addUser(user,{through: {number: 30,inteam: 1});`, the program only inserts id_user and id_team, it doesn't work for number and inteam. How can I properly use it?

**create-user_team.js**

```
'use strict';
/** @type {import('sequelize-cli').Migration} */
module.exports = {
  async up(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    await queryInterface.createTable('user_team', {
      id_user: {
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true,
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        references: {
          model: 'Users',
          key: 'id'
        }
      },
      id_team: {
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true,
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        references: {
          model: 'Teams',
          key: 'id'
        }
      },
      number: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER
      },
      inteam: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER
      },
      createdAt:  { allowNull: false, type: 'TIMESTAMP', defaultValue: Sequelize.literal('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP') },
      updatedAt: { allowNull: false, type: 'TIMESTAMP', defaultValue: Sequelize.literal('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP') }
    });
    
  },
  async down(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    await queryInterface.dropTable('user_team');
  }
};
```

Model **users.js**

```
'use strict';
const {
  Model
} = require('sequelize');
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class User extends Model {
    /**
     * Helper method for defining associations.
     * This method is not a part of Sequelize lifecycle.
     * The `models/index` file will call this method automatically.
     */
    static associate(models) {
      // define association here      
      User.belongsToMany(models.Team,{through: 'user_team', foreignKey: 'id_user',as: 'teams'})
    
    }
    toJSON()
    {
      return {...this.get(), role_id: undefined}
    }
  }
  User.init({
    username: DataTypes.STRING,
    password: DataTypes.STRING,
    email: DataTypes.STRING,
    hinhanh: DataTypes.STRING
  }, {
    sequelize,
    modelName: 'User',
  });
  return User;
};
```

Model **team.js**

```
'use strict';
const {
  Model
} = require('sequelize');
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class Team extends Model {
    /**
     * Helper method for defining associations.
     * This method is not a part of Sequelize lifecycle.
     * The `models/index` file will call this method automatically.
     */
    static associate(models) {
      // define association here
      Team.belongsToMany(models.User,{through: 'user_team', foreignKey: 'id_team',as: 'users',})
      


    }
    toJSON()
    {
      return {...this.get()}
    }
  }
  Team.init({
    name: DataTypes.STRING,
    namthanhlap: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    hinhanh: DataTypes.STRING
  }, {
    sequelize,
    modelName: 'Team',
  });
  return Team;
};
```

Please help me :( Thank for all.

[In DB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gy0YU.png)

**This is query in Sequelize**
Executing (default): SELECT "createdAt", "updatedAt", "id_team", "id_user" FROM "user_team" AS "user_team" WHERE "user_team"."id_team" = 1 AND "user_team"."id_user" IN (11);
Executing (default): INSERT INTO "user_team" ("createdAt","updatedAt","id_team","id_user") VALUES ('2023-07-15 16:49:21.809
+00:00','2023-07-15 16:49:21.809 +00:00',1,11) RETURNING "createdAt","updatedAt","id_team","id_user";